# linear gradient with divs

Tags: html, css

I need to do something like this  example using more than two divs. For instance, one div will be the grey div and other the green div.

Is it possible to do generic without specify the percent width?

```css
#test {
    height: 50px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, grey 0%,grey 50%, green 50%,green 100%);
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
   Hello World!
</div>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. What two divs? How should each be treated?

Comment: i need something like this : <div id="test"><div class="grey_class"/><div class="green_class"/></div> and my text over the div. My comment helped?

Comment: Like what? Are you trying to link an image

Comment: For instance, each color is a div. And i need to fix the text over this divs who are next to each other.

Comment: Wait, are you trying to put individual backgrounds around each separate word regardless of how may words there are? Is that it?

Comment: I trying to put two or n color as background in "my text", however if i use gradient, i need to specify the percent of each color. And this color will be at css file.

Comment: You can't do what **I think** you are trying to do without wrapping each word in it's own `span` and applying individual colors to those. Javascript could probably do something...but not CSS.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/p637cqmu/

Comment: That was my fear. Sorry for the mess! LOL
I saw your example =D but alternating colors is not the solution for me. Thanks for all

Comment: That was just an example but it depend on how many words you have s to what method you use. I'd be thinking in terms of javascript and an array of colors myself but it really depends on the overall effect you are trying to acheive

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can "cheat" and achieve the effect you want without having to specify a completely new gradient for each `div` by combining a single colour gradient with a `backgroud-color` and then setting the gradient's width with `background-size`. You'll also need to set the `background-repeat` property to `no-repeat` to prevent the gradient from filling the elements.

Here's a quick example:

```css
div{
    background:green linear-gradient(0deg,grey,grey) no-repeat;
    height:50px;
    margin:0 0 10px;
}
#quarter{
  background-size:25% 100%;
}
#third{
  background-size:33.333% 100%;
}
#half{
  background-size:50% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="quarter"></div>
<div id="third"></div>
<div id="half"></div>
```

Comment: Nice but still has numbers. You'd just moved them from the gradient to the background-size.

Comment: Yeah, I just reread the question and it is open to interpretation. The use of the word "generic" led me to believe this is what Coto was looking for.